# How to download the historical file version content using CSOM

Tags: development

I am trying to download the previous version of a document from _vti_history location of the file using client object model but the OpenBinaryDirect is giving

> not found 402 error

for URL.

My code is as given below

```
public int GetStreamFromFile(string docid, string lib, string fileurl, ClientContext clientContext, int iuserid, string Version, bool isCurrrent)
{
if(!isCurrent) 
{
List LibraryName = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(lib); 
clientContext.Load(LibraryName);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "" + fileurl +
"";
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collListItem = LibraryName.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(item => item.Id, item => item["FileLeafRef"], item => item["LinkFilename"],
item => item["FileRef"], item => item["File_x0020_Size"], item => item["DocIcon"], item => item.File.Versions));
//clientContext.Load(collListItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
//string fileurl1 = (string)oListItem["FileRef"]; 
//string filename = (string)oListItem["LinkFilename"];

foreach (FileVersion version in oListItem.File.Versions)
{
if (Version == version.VersionLabel)
{
//Added excutequery to get object one more time as per blog
//http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/88a05256-8694-4e40-863d-6c77512e079b
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
FileInformation fileInformation = ClientOM.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext,version.Url);
bytesarr = ReadFully(fileInformation.Stream); 
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. When I try to download a historical file using OpenBinaryDirect(), I get an error mentioning "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.". However, If I pass the same URL through web browser, I am able to download the file. Couple of more points: 1. I even tried to modify the URL a bit by adding "ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + version.Url" for the Relative URL
2. Tried to modify the URL by adding just the "/"

Comment: did you get any solutions for this problem? I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 5):

You can access versions of a document via SharePoint's version history web service.

Use the URL to the version you want to view. For example:
**`http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/DocLib/Book1.xls`** in the left window, and...
**`http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/1024/DocLib/Book1.xls`** in the right window will compare versions 1.0 and 2.0 of the same document item.

With the version number in hand (`version.VersionLabel` in your code), you can generate the proper URL using the following formula:
**Major Version * 512 + Minor Version**

...and use [shushank sharma's solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/76254/7894) to get the content.

While it's not as sexy as using the CSOM for the entire solution, it'll get you past this hurdle and on to the next! :-)

See below for an explanation of the version numbers ("512" and "1024" in the URLs above), taken from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/99261c97-efda-4061-9bf9-10ec47923c36/where-are-version-history-documents-stored.

---

> Canonical path (top-most version)
>
> `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/Documents/Book1.xlsx`
>
> revision paths
>
> You could access the previous version document like following.
>
> `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/Documents/Book1.xlsx`
>   (Accessing version 1.0)
>
> One thing to note if you have only one version of the document then
>   this will give 404 page not found error. You must use the canonical path to retrieve the top-most version.
>
> _vti_history - Virtual directory
>
> 512 - See the following table then you could understa
>
> “1” = version “0.1“
>
> `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/1/Documents/Book1.xlsx`
>
> “2” = version “0.2“
>
> `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/2/Documents/Book1.xlsx`
>
> “512” = version “1.0“
>
> `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/Documents/Book1.xls`
>
> “1025” = version “2.1“
>
> `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/1025/Documents/Book1.xls`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (I have 3 textboxes - Web Url / Item Url / Save To Path):

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(txtWebUrl.Text))
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(txtItemUrl.Text);

                clientContext.Load(file, item => item.Name);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var versions = file.Versions;
                clientContext.Load(versions);

                var oldVersions = clientContext.LoadQuery(versions.Where(v => v != null));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                                                                              

                if (oldVersions != null)
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion _version in oldVersions)
                    {
                        clientContext.Load(_version, item => item.VersionLabel);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        if (!Directory.Exists(txtSaveTo.Text))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(txtSaveTo.Text);
                        }

                        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                        {
                            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                            string filePath = Path.Combine(txtSaveTo.Text, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) + _version.VersionLabel + ".xml");
                            wc.DownloadFile(txtWebUrl.Text + _version.Url, filePath);
                        }                        
                    }                    
                }                
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

By far the best example with sample code:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-september-2017/

Answer (score 1):

Use WebClient to download Different versions of file.

Edit:
Sorry for Late Answer
This is snipest of C# Code.

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client ->Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserNameText, PasswordText);       System.IO.Stream Data = client .OpenRead(url);
```

Now you can parse data using `Data` object of `System.IO.Stream` class with its functions like(Data .ReadByte(); which read byte by byte).
Find more reference for `System.IO.Stream` on MSDN

Comment: Could you provide some more details, please?

Comment: This answer does not really help if you do not add more details (like a code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with SharePoint 2013 with Claims - the user agent header was the key for me.

```
        private System.Net.WebClient SPWebClient() {

            if (_SPWebClient != null) return _SPWebClient;

            _SPWebClient = new WebClient {

                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_sharePointUser, _sharePointPassword, _sharePointDomain)

            };

            // for claims based auth
            _SPWebClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

            _SPWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC)";

            return _SPWebClient;

        }

        var versions = file.Versions;

        this.SharePointContext.Load(versions);

        this.SharePointContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var version in versions) {

            var versionStream = this.SharePointWebClient.OpenRead($"{this.SharePointUrl}/{version.Url}");

            // do something useful

        }
```