# Be able to view old version (revision) of Word, Excel, Visio Online document on O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, document

When you want to view a document Online, for example Word Document, the Url of the document is :

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B3DDF11BE-5043-4B3F-8EFE-FD53381F537A%7D&file=Document.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true

The GUID is the UniqueID of the document in SharePoint.

It would be very interesting to select an older version of the document to view using a syntax like underneath (for the revision 1 of a document) as when you want to download a specific revision of a document?

For Downloading the revision 1 of MyDocument.docx the syntax is :

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_vti_history/512/Documents%20partages/MyDocument.docx

For viewing this underneath URL could be great:

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/mysite/_vti_history/512/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B3DDF11BE-5043-4B3F-8EFE-FD53381F537A%7D&file=Document.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true

Answer (score 0):

You could access the previous version document like following.

http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/Documents/Book1.xlsx (Accessing version 1.0)

One thing to note if you have only one version of the document then this will give 404 page not found error.

_vti_history - Virtual directory

512 - See the following table then you could understa

“1” = version “0.1“

http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/1/Documents/Book1.xlsx

“2” = version “0.2“

http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/2/Documents/Book1.xlsx

“512” = version “1.0“

http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/Documents/Book1.xls

“1025” = version “2.1“

http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/1025/Documents/Book1.xls

Formula : Major Version * 512 + Minor Version

Reference: [How to download the historical file version content using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67345/how-to-download-the-historical-file-version-content-using-csom/76254#76254)

Comment: Hello @jerry, thank you for that, I'm aware of that but I don't want to download it, I just want to view it (with VisioOnline, with Word online or with Excel Online) without downloading it.