# MS Project [Standard 16] Versioning Issue on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history, ms-project

For some reason, a MS Project [Standard 16] file stored on SharePoint Online is now loading an older version which is months out-of-date.

My next step was to retrieve an older version via the "Version History" but I have noticed that all versions from 0.44 to 0.68 are loading exactly the same out-of-date one as the latest?

I have not had this problem before with this MS Project file and have always been able to save, check-in and view the latest version. I suspect the issue happened between 30-Oct-19 and 5-Dec-19.

Do you have any troubleshooting ideas or suggestions which may have caused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it sounds like all the versions between 0.44 and 0.68 are in fact an older version? Have a try on downloading the version history of that file via web service with link like `http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/DocLib/Book1.xls` as this thread
[How to download the historical file version content using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67345/how-to-download-the-historical-file-version-content-using-csom)
Check if you have a the same issue with the filed downalded

If you lose some certain version of that specific file, it may be better for you to open a service request for more help.